# How does VS 2010 SP1 choose the version of boost lib files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

Under the boost library directory, I can see the following files:

libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_46_1.lib
   libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_46_1.pdb
   libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.lib
   libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_46_1.lib
   libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_46_1.pdb
   libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib
   libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-1_47.lib
   libboost_filesystem-vc90-mt-gd-1_47.lib

When I build the solution, the following warning is reported:

> Warning   15  warning LNK4099: PDB
>   'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.pdb' was not found with
>   'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.lib(codecvt_error_category.obj)' or
>   at 'C:\source\Release\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.pdb'; linking
>   object as if no debug
>   info  C:\source\Project1\libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.lib(codecvt_error_category.obj)

As you can see VS2010 chooses the version of `libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.lib`, since we don't have the `libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47.pdb` under the same directory, the linker complains.

**Quesition**> What is the method used by VS2010 to choose which version of boost library to link?

For example, what if we have the following libraries file,

libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_46_1.lib
   libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_47_1.pdb
   libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-1_49_1.lib

Which version will be chosen by VS2010?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's determined by #pragma statements in the boost headers -- so whatever version of the header you end up including, that's what version of the lib it will try to link.

Specifically, you can find this in boost/config/auto_link.hpp, and it looks like this:

```
#  pragma comment(lib, BOOST_LIB_PREFIX BOOST_STRINGIZE(BOOST_LIB_NAME) BOOST_LIB_THREAD_OPT BOOST_LIB_RT_OPT ".lib")
```

It's weird that "#pragma comment" actually instructs the linker to do something... but that's how MS did it...

Answer (score 2):

Boost version is defined here:

C:\boost1.47\boost\version.hpp

```
//
//  BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION
//  but as a *string* in the form "x_y[_z]" where x is the major version
//  number, y is the minor version number, and z is the patch level if not 0.
//  This is used by <config/auto_link.hpp> to select which library version to link to.

#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_47"
```

C:\boost1.49\boost\version.hpp

```
//
//  BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION
//  but as a *string* in the form "x_y[_z]" where x is the major version
//  number, y is the minor version number, and z is the patch level if not 0.
//  This is used by <config/auto_link.hpp> to select which library version to link to.

#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_49"
```

Boost library name is formed as follows:

C:\boost1.49\boost\config\auto_link.hpp

```
//
// now include the lib:
//
#if defined(BOOST_LIB_NAME) \
      && defined(BOOST_LIB_PREFIX) \
      && defined(BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET) \
      && defined(BOOST_LIB_THREAD_OPT) \
      && defined(BOOST_LIB_RT_OPT) \
      && defined(BOOST_LIB_VERSION)
```